# Back button loop on Sign In screen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm following the [Firebase in a Weekend course (Android) from Udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud0352) on `Android Studio`. On [Lesson 36. Handling Cancelled Sign In](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud0352/lessons/daa58d76-0146-4c52-b5d8-45e32a3dfb08/concepts/48022087-c4c2-4f2d-b09b-91a7b908e9de) from Saturday it is showed how to fix a bug related to when you press the "Back button" and the app keeps showing the Sign In screen on an endless loop. This is the code that supposedly fix the issue, the `onActivityResult` function:

```
@Override  // Added manually.
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(requestCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Notice that at the bottom I added a `Toaster` to display the `requestCode` variable value:

`Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(requestCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

**`requestCode` is always `1`** (and always equals the `RC_SIGN_IN` constant value) after signing out or even when the app is started for the first time.

Things I've tried: wiped data/cache, reinstalled app, disabled/enabled `Don't keep activities` in `Developer options`.

Here's the full `MainActivity.java` code:

https://ideone.com/YyF0tr

[I've already asked on the course's forums](https://discussions.udacity.com/t/back-button-loop-on-sign-in-screen/902755) but haven't had an answer yet, and solutions provided for similar problem didn't solve my issue.

I'm using a physical LG G3 to test the app.

**UPDATE:**

`resultCode` returns `0`. Not to be confused with `requestCode` which always returns `1` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, [It Takes Guts And Humility To Admit That You Are Wrong](https://medium.com/@XEN_Life/it-takes-guts-and-humility-to-admit-that-you-are-wrong-74ab425b09b0) but it happends very often when one explores a new technology and is part of the learning curve. The issue is my `else if` statement. It should be nested within the second `if` statement:

**It says:**

```
        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
```

**It should say:**

```
        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
```

Now the back button loop is gone.